# Read multiple files from a directory using Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, kaggle

I am trying to solve this [problem](https://www.kaggle.com/c/axa-driver-telematics-analysis) at kaggle using spark:

the hierarchy of input is like this :

```
drivers/{driver_id}/trip#.csv
e.g., drivers/1/1.csv
      drivers/1/2.csv
      drivers/2/1.csv
```

I want to read the parent directory **"drivers"** and for each sub directory i would like to create a **pairRDD** with key as **(sub_directory,file_name)** and value as the content of the file

I checked [this](http://www.infoobjects.com/spark-core-sc-textfile-vs-sc-wholetextfiles/) link and tried to use

```
val text = sc.wholeTextFiles("drivers")
text.collect()
```

this failed with error :

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileInputFormat$OneFileInfo.<init>(CombineFileInputFormat.java:591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileInputFormat.getMoreSplits(CombineFileInputFormat.java:283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileInputFormat.getSplits(CombineFileInputFormat.java:243)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.WholeTextFileRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1779)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:885)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:884)
```

but when i run the below code, it works.

```
val text =  sc.wholeTextFiles("drivers/1")
text.collect()
```

but I don't want to do this, since here i will have to read the directory **drivers** and loop the files and call **wholeTextFiles** for each entry.

Comment: Have you tried val text = sc.wholeTextFiles("drivers/*")

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
sc.textfile("path/*/**") or sc.wholeTextFiles("path/*")
```

You can use this piece of code. Because spark internally lists all the possible values of a folder and subfolder so it can cost you time on large datasets. Instead of that you can use Unions for the same purpose.

Pass this List object which contains the locations to the following piece of code, note : sc is an object of SQLContext

```
var df: DataFrame = null;
  for (file <- files) {
    val fileDf= sc.textFile(file)
    if (df!= null) {
      df= df.unionAll(fileDf)
    } else {
      df= fileDf
    }
  }
```

Now you got a final Unified RDD i.e. df