# How to avoid "Not a file" exceptions when reading from HDFS with spark

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, emr, s3distcp

I copy a tree of files from S3 to HDFS with [S3DistCP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html) in an initial EMR step. `hdfs dfs -ls -R hdfs:///data_dir` shows the expected files, which look something like:

```
/data_dir/year=2015/
/data_dir/year=2015/month=01/
/data_dir/year=2015/month=01/day=01/
/data_dir/year=2015/month=01/day=01/data01.12345678
/data_dir/year=2015/month=01/day=01/data02.12345678
/data_dir/year=2015/month=01/day=01/data03.12345678
```

The 'directories' are listed as zero-byte files.

I then run a spark step which needs to read these files. The loading code is thus:

```
sqlctx.read.json('hdfs:///data_dir, schema=schema)
```

The job fails with a java exception

```
java.io.IOException: Not a file: hdfs://10.159.123.38:9000/data_dir/year=2015
```

I had (perhaps naively) assumed that spark would recursively descend the 'dir tree' and load the data files. If I point to S3 it loads the data successfully.

Am I misunderstanding HDFS? Can I tell spark to ignore zero-byte files? Can i use S3DistCp to flatten the tree?

Comment: I can't tell for DataFrame API, but in pure Spark, i.e. with RDD's, you can load all files in a directory with `SparkContext.wholeTextFiles(*path*)`, see [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext) for more.

Comment: How about "/data_dir/*/*/*/*.*" ? From my experience spark does not load files recursively in sub directories.

Comment: @WoodChopper Thanks, you are correct. The HDFS driver does not recursively descend the file hierarchy.

Comment: yw :) I guess its just not HDFS even with local file system.

Answer (score 6):

In Hadoop configuration for current spark context, configure "recursive" read for Hadoop InputFormat before to get the sql ctx

```
val hadoopConf = sparkCtx.hadoopConfiguration
hadoopConf.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive", "true")
```

This will give the solution for "not a file".
Next, to read multiple files:

[Hadoop job taking input files from multiple directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593243/hadoop-job-taking-input-files-from-multiple-directories)

or union the list of files into single dataframe :

[Read multiple files from a directory using Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31051107/read-multiple-files-from-a-directory-using-spark)

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved with :

```
spark-submit ...
    --conf spark.hadoop.mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive=true \
    --conf spark.hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories=true \
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameters must be set in this way in spark version 2.1.0 :

```
.set("spark.hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories","true")
.set("spark.hadoop.mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive","true")
```