# How to load multiple files in order of their arrival in spark data frame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-2.10

I have to load millions of XML files from S3 and process it in the spark .
But loading of all files should be done in specific order .
So for example I have appended time series in the name of the folder ,Now I need to sort all files by time series prefix and load it in the spark in same sorted order .

Order of the files should not change while loading into spark data frame .

Can we do this in spark?

Comment: _But loading of all files should be done in specific order_ - sounds like you're making really dangerous assumptions here and it is likely to be [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: The answer was answered at [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31051107/read-multiple-files-from-a-directory-using-spark) SO question.